# Query for small/capital letter in PostgreSQL and SQLITE3

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, tkinter

How can I select record from the database no matter what case of letter is used by the user in tkinter, small or capital? In MySQL I used BINARY, but what about PostgreSQL and SQLITE?

Comment: So you want python code to make a database query where you are selecting records using one letter that might be lower or upper case in PostgreSQL or SQLITE?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the default collation is case-insensitive. In SQLite, it's binary. And in PostgreSQL it default to the OS-defined collation for the locale.

You can force a case-insensitive match by using `lower`:

```
select a from f where lower(a) = lower('myString')
```

In PostgreSQL you can also use a case-insensitive data type for the column like `citext`

```
create table a (f citext);
```

Another option is to use [`ilike`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html) which ignores case. (Note that special characters should be escaped with `ilike` if you want a literal match.)

```
select f from a where f ilike 'myString';
```

In SQLite you can use the directive `collate nocase` in the column definition.

```
create table a (f text collate nocase);
```

Or in the query:

```
select f from a where f = 'myString` collate nocase;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!